# $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[H]$ then what can be said about $G$ and $H$?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

The question in title has been considered for finite groups $G$ and $H$, but I do not know its situation, how far it is known whether $G$ and $H$ could be isomorphic. I have two simple questions regarding it.

**Q.0** If $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong \mathbb{Z}[H]$ then $|G|$ should be $|H|$; because, $G$ is a free basis for the *free additive abelian group $\mathbb{Z}[G]$*, am I right?  (I am asking this because in Isaac's character theory, I saw something different argument, not too lengthy, but I was thinking for the above natural arguments.)

**Q.1** Are there known examples of finite groups $G\ncong H$ with $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong \mathbb{Z}[H]$? (In the book of character theory by Isaacs, he stated for metablelian groups $G,H$, $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong \mathbb{Z}[H]$ implies $G\cong H$; it was proved by Whitcomb, in $1970$; but book has not been further revised, I don't known what is done after $1970$).

Comment: For Q. 0 the answer is yes for the reason you say. I am finding Qn 2 confusing. What did Isaacs say is true - that there are known examples? If so then the answer is obviously yes.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks for noticing the error in question 1. I corrected it.

Comment: @Derek: By any chance, do you know the corresponding statement for $\mathbb{C}[G]\cong\mathbb{C}[H]$? Is it easier to find a counter-example in this case?

Comment: @Prism: non-isomorphic abelian groups of same order, or extra-special p-groups of same order, dihedral and quaternion groups of order 8, etc. (Instead of fields, if we consider rings, then there are less counterexamples.)

Comment: @Beginner: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right about the zeroth question.

For the first, a counterexample was constructed by Hertweck in 2001. There are two non-isomorphic groups $G$ and $H$ of order $2^{21}97^{28}$ with $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong\mathbb{Z}[H]$.

Comment: Hertweek is the cousin of Hertweck ...

Comment: @GEdgar Whoops! Fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

This isomorphism problem was stated by Higman in this thesis $1940$: 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong\mathbb{Z}[H] \Longrightarrow G\cong H ?
$$
It is true for nilpotent groups, for metabelian groups (Whitcomp $1968$), and was disproved by Hertweck in $2001$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632372/minimal-counterexamples-of-the-isomorphism-problem-for-integral-group-rings).

Comment: +1. By the way, would you have any idea concerning [this related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259117/) question on MO?

Comment: @Watson Thank you! The MO question looks interesting, and is perhaps not so easy.